# Unable to get windows events from suspend windows process hooked using SetWindowsHookEx and SetWindowsHook api's

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to implement a windows application to manage other processes state suspend and resume to save power.

My idea is to suspend the process when the process, focus lost and resume the process when user access the process.

I am able to suspend a process (ex: notepad process) when its losses the focus or user switches to different app. I am getting the user inputs through SetWindowsHookEx.

once after i suspend the process when user switches to different app, I am not getting any hook event to resume the process when user tries to access process back.

And i also tried getting event using SetWindowsHook api but no luck.

Please let me know, if any why to get the notification when user tried accessing suspended process to resume it

code to install hook:

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(L"NotePad", NULL);
if (!hWnd)
{
    WriteLog("get app handle failed\n");
    return false;
}
DWORD processId;
DWORD threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &processId);
ghKeyHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, MsgHookProc, ghInstance, threadId);
```

Proc callback:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MsgHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    WriteLog("entering proc hook\n");
}
```

Comment: Of course, after you suspend ui thread, this thread ( and your hook) not got any events

Comment: @RbMm  Please suggest if you know any other ways to get notified when suspended process accessed by user.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might have more luck with a CBT or shell hook but suspending a process that has a HWND is never going to end well.

- You will slow down broadcasted messages and DDE.
- The app you suspended will miss notification messages it has registered for (power, WTS etc.).

Trying to "save power" this way is pointless anyway. When Notepad is idle it is just going to be waiting on an event in kernel mode (because it called `GetMessage`) and it will consume 0% CPU.

If you want to do this, perhaps instead you could lower the priority of certain processes? Keep in mind that the foreground process already gets priority boost from Windows.

Comment: Hi Anders,
Thanks for your inputs.

1. I have tried WH_CALLWNDPROC, WH_CBT,WH_MOUSE, WH_KEYBOARD, WH_SHELL WH_DEBUG Hooks but no luck.

2. Thanks i wasn't knowing slows downs the process speed, But this is the POC what i am doing, I am fine with little lag

3. Notepad i used for just POC only, Will be adding few more process.

Please suggest if any other better method if you know to achieve my Idea

Comment: Try SetWinEventHook